# Why can we breathe only oxygen?

Tags: zoology, botany, cellular-respiration

Plants has the capacity to take in both CO<sub>2</sub> and oxygen, that's during day CO<sub>2</sub> and at night oxygen. Why don't humans have such a capability?

Comment: Remember that O2 is also taken by the plants during the day !

Answer (score 1):

You should have a look biological processes which are:

- cellular respiration
- photosynthesis

Loosly speaking, these two processes are just the opposite but deal with the same chemical compunds.

$C_6H_{12}O_6 + 6O_2 \xrightleftharpoons\  6CO_2 + 6H_2O (+ Energy)$

or in words...

**glucose + Oxygen $\xrightleftharpoons\ $ Carbon Dioxide + Water (+ Energy)**

From left to right is the process of respiration and from right to left is the process of photosynthesis.

- Respiration releases energy from glucose (sugar). Therefore, animals, plants, fungi respire in order to get their energy from their food. More information on the chemical pathways on  [Krebs cycle (or citric acid cycle)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Citric_acid_cycle). The main [organelle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Organelle) involved in celullar respiration is the [mitochondrion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mitochondrion). Note: (Loosely speaking) the glucose is the end product of the [digestion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digestion)
- photosynthesis allows organisms to create its own tissues from water and $CO_2$. But this cost energy. This is why plants use capture the energy form the sun with their leaves. More information on the chemical pathways on [Calvin Cycle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calvin_cycle#Calvin_Cycle). The main organelle involved in photosynthesis is the [chloroplast](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chloroplast).

Note: In our lungs comes air which is a mixture of different gases (just like coke (Coca-Cola) is a mixture of different compounds). The two main compounds of air are Nitrogen (~78%) and Oxygen (~21%). We use only Oxygen. More info on the air composition [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atmosphere_of_Earth#Composition)

Answer (score 0):

Humans breathe in air, which contains both oxygen and carbon dioxide. But we do not photosynthesise and so we do not take in CO<sub>2</sub>. The CO<sub>2</sub> produced from respiration in our body builds up in the blood and through diffusion escapes into the lungs and out when we exhale.